# can anyone help me with my add row formarray

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, formarray

my modal and my textbox

[image]

once i click the modal

[image]

when i click the value in modal table

[image]

adding a row

[image]

selecting again value for my second row

[image]

once i select why my first row get the value too?

[image]

[angular index for formarray can anyone tell whats wrong with my codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72811041/angular-index-for-formarray-can-anyone-tell-whats-wrong-with-my-codes)

here's the link of the code

let me know please I'm stuck of this one

Comment: Please create a stackblitz, the question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Because `id:[0]`. When you create a new new row you are always pushing same id. When closing your modal `ItemDialogComponent`, it should return the item selected from the modal (response). Your return `response` right now is just a string, but make it return an obj. And you pass that returned obj to `addRow(response)` to be added to `this.Form`.

Comment: can you show me some reference code, I'm clueless

Comment: Please make a Stackblitz of your code, attach it to this post and everyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the input in a div and add the formGroupName there instead

```
<div [formGroupName]="I">
<input>
</div>
```